Is my code structurally correct? [about image of buffer counts]
I am using a basler camera and I am working on the code to implement the parameters in visual studio.
I created the following code to display the buffer count of an image in a dialog, and I'm wondering if it's structurally correct, grammatical errors aside. (Sorry for the basic error)
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "imageviewer12.h"
#include "imageviewer12Dlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#ifdef PYLON_WIN_BUILD

#endif

void Cimageviewer12Dlg::OnEnChangeEdit3()
{
    int width = rect.Width();  
    int height = rect.Height();
    int bpp = 8; 

    int buffercount = (width * height * 8)/8;

    CString buffercount;

    buffercount.Format(_T("%d"), buffercount);

    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT3,buffercount);
}

Thanks.

You have two variables called buffercount, that is not legal. Also I wonder what you think the difference is between (width * height * 8)/8 and the simpler width * height, and why there is an unused variable bpp.

Also if you used the function SetDlgItemInt instead of SetDlgItemText then you would not need to convert your integer to a string.

Putting all that together this seems to be a shorter version of your code void Cimageviewer12Dlg::OnEnChangeEdit3() { SetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT3, rect.Width() * rect.Height()); }. But shorter does not mean better.

For code reviews, there's the Code Review SE.  But please read about their posting rules first.

With that said, width * height * 8 might overflow, leading to undefined behavior.

There is one other issue, EN_CHANGE is sent when the user changes the text in an edit control. So your code is changing the text in an edit control after the user has taken some action to change the text in (apparently) the same edit control. That is a strange thing to be doing. I understand that you want your program to change the contents of this edit control but I wonder it you have chosen the right place to do it.

Thanks for the kind reply and @john you're right, it looks like I put the code in the wrong place. I put it inside another code and it works (live button). It comes out a little weird, but I think I can fix it. Thanks so much!!
